# Change text of QPushButton on Click

Tags: python-3.x, text, pyqt5, qpushbutton

So I have been searching around but can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I would like to update the text of a QPushButton when it is clicked. Every time i run my code it crashes with no error message. Please Could someone help me? i have attached the relevant section of my code below:

```
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.OuterSwitch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OuterDoorControl"))
    self.InnerSwitch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "InnerDoorControl"))
```

...

```
class ControlMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(ControlMainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.ui.OuterSwitch.clicked.connect(self.OuterControl)
    self.ui.InnerSwitch.clicked.connect(self.InnerControl)


def OuterControl(self):
    if GPIO.input(Inner)==0: #InnerDoorOpen
        return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH),print("Please Close Inner Door")
    elif GPIO.input(Outer) ==1: #Outer Door Close
        self.OuterSwitch.setText(_translate("MainWindow","Close Outer Door"))
        QApplication.processEvents()
        return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.LOW) #Open Outer Door
    elif GPIO.input(Outer) == 0: #OuterDoor Open
        self.ui.InnerSwitch.setEnabled(False)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000,partial(self.ui.InnerSwitch.setEnabled,True))
        return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH) #Close OuterDoor
```

The OuterSwitch and InnerSwitch are the objectnames for the two push buttons I am using. I am using PyQt5 and designed the Gui using QtDesigner. I am using Python 3.7.

Please can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by using this line of code:

```
elif GPIO.input(Outer) ==1: #Outer Door Close
    self.ui.OuterSwitch.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow","Close Outer Door",None))
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
```

I needed to select the correct API.